# How to start server Phoenix from script and wait till it's ready?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

It's possible to seed database in Phoenix using this command:

```
mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

I'd like to seed the application via JSON API, so instead of DB calls there will be bunch of HTTP requests to the server in `seeds.exs`, like:

```
...
# Creating post.
HTTPoison.post! "http://localhost:4000/posts", Poison.encode!({name: "My post"}), 
  [{"Content-Type", "application/json"}]
...
```

But, unfortunately running the `seed.exs` script doesn't start the server.

How can I change the `seeds.exs` script so that it will start the server, wait till it's fully started and then proceed with HTTP calls?

Comment: I would consider wrapping that in a shell script.